# no response using iodocs

Tags: node.js, redis, mashery, iodocs

HI I have deployed the iodocs locally,and its working for the samples given.
but for my api its giving empty response.

here is what i appended to /data/apiconfig.json

```
"cloudspokes": {
    "name": "cloudspokes",
    "protocol": "http",
    "baseURL": "cloudspokes.com",
    "publicPath": "",
    "auth": ""
}
```

and here is  /data/cloudspokes.json

```
{
"endpoints":[
  {
     "name":"Challenges",
     "methods":[
        {
           "MethodName":"challenges",
           "Synopsis":"This method returns a list of challenges.",
           "HTTPMethod":"GET",
           "URI":"/challenges.json",
           "RequiresOAuth":"N",
           "parameters":[

            ]
        }

      ]
  }

 ]
}
```

iodocs is rendering the interface correctly 
[image]

also going to http://cloudspokes.com/challenges.json returns non empty response.
I am new to this , please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to update your **apiconfig.json** block for cloudspokes to look like this:

```
"cloudspokes": {
    "name": "cloudspokes",
    "protocol": "http",
    "baseURL": "www.cloudspokes.com",
    "publicPath": "",
    "auth": ""
}
```

The difference is that I added the "www." prefix to the *baseURL* hostname. How did I know you needed this? Because I turned on debugging and saw that it was throwing a 301 (redirect). Check the **config.json** file and change *debug* to be *true* and you'll see the same thing.

But again, quick fix, just add **www.** to the *baseURL*, and you're all set.

Comment: yes,thanks.found the solution myself few days ago.you may have a look at finished application : http://cloudspokesapi.cloudfoundry.com/